# How to set NULL value by arcpy.da.InsertCursor on date column?

Tags: python, arcpy, cursor

How to set NULL value by arcpy.da.InsertCursor on date column?

I try insert "NULL", None, '', 0

```
dictIN= [{'field1':"test1",'date1':'01-02-2015','date2':''},\
 {'field1':"test2",'date1':'01-02-2015','date2':'01-02-2015'},\
 {'field1':"test3",'date1':'','date2':''},\
 {'field1':"test4",'date1':'01-02-2015','date2':''}]


def setNULLIf(field):
    if field == '':
        return None #try NULL,'',0
    else: return field

cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(GDB,("field1", "date1", "date2"))
for x in dictIN:
    cursor.insertRow((x['field1'], setNULLIf(x['date1']), setNULLIf(x['date2'])))
```

Is it possible by arcpy.da ?
I use ArcGIS 10.2. I try insert data to GDB file.

Comment: What code did you use to try and do this?  Please **edit** your question to include a code snippet.  I also recommend that you copy the information about using a date field, that currently only appears in the title where it is easily overlooked, down into the question body.

Comment: Why don't you just omit the date field in the InsertCursor? Only the fields specified in the cursor will be filled in.

Comment: Please edit the question to specify 1) the version of ArcGIS, and 2) the cursor target data source type (FGDB, shapefile, EGDB,...)

Comment: You are missing a quotation before field1 , cursor.insertRow((x[field1'], which must be cursor.insertRow((x['field1']

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are missing `date2` in `dictIN`:

Change it:

```
dictIN= [{'field1':"test1",'date1':'01-02-2015','date2':''},\
 {'field1':"test2",'date1':'01-02-2015','date2':'01-02-2015'},\
 {'field1':"test3",'date1':'','date2':''},\
 {'field1':"test4",'date1':'01-02-2015','date2':''}]
```

Full code is:

```
dictIN= [{'field1':"test1",'date1':'01-02-2015','date2':''},\
 {'field1':"test2",'date1':'01-02-2015','date2':'01-02-2015'},\
 {'field1':"test3",'date1':'','date2':''},\
 {'field1':"test4",'date1':'01-02-2015','date2':''}]


def setNULLIf(field):
    if field == '':
        return None #try NULL,'',0
    else: return field

cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(GDB,("field1", "date1", "date2"))
for x in dictIN:
    print (x['field1'], setNULLIf(x['date1']), setNULLIf(x['date2']))

    cursor.insertRow((x['field1'], setNULLIf(x['date1']), setNULLIf(x['date2'])))
```

Full code returns this to a new feature class in GDB with you fileds:
[image]

**If code is not working try to check GDB field parameters - are they nullable?**

Answer (score 4):

A simple test shows that `None` should work. See Mr. Che's answer to see what else was wrong.

```
with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(mytable, ["date"]) as cursor:
    cursor.insertRow([None])
```